# Pushsharp: IOS notifications are working locally but not on live server

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

Pushsharp IOS notifications are working locally but not on live server, I can't even track where the error, its not triggering any of below events, Could anyone suggest any tips to debug. 
Do I need to do some settings on Server?
Below is my code.

```
PushBroker push = new PushBroker();
    push.OnNotificationSent += NotificationSent;
    push.OnChannelException += ChannelException;
    push.OnServiceException += ServiceException;
    push.OnNotificationFailed += NotificationFailed;
    push.OnDeviceSubscriptionExpired += DeviceSubscriptionExpired;
    push.OnDeviceSubscriptionChanged += DeviceSubscriptionChanged;
    push.OnChannelCreated += ChannelCreated;
    push.OnChannelDestroyed += ChannelDestroyed;
    push.RegisterAppleService(new ApplePushChannelSettings(appleCert, "xxx"));

push.QueueNotification(new AppleNotification()
                     .ForDeviceToken("toked ID here") //dev
                     .WithAlert(msg)
                     .WithBadge(7)
                     .WithSound("sound.caf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the APNS production certificate instead of the development one, see ["Provisioning and Development" in the documentation:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)

> You must get separate certificates for the development environment and
>   the production environment. The certificates are associated with an
>   identifier of the app that is the recipient of remote notifications;
>   this identifier includes the app’s bundle ID. When you create a
>   provisioning profile for one of the environments, the requisite
>   entitlements are automatically added to the profile, including the
>   entitlement specific to remote notifications, . The
>   two provisioning profiles are called Development and Distribution. The
>   Distribution provisioning profile is a requirement for submitting your
>   app to the App Store.